# What is the moment of inertia of a free electron?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin, moment-of-inertia

Well, elementary particles have no moment of inertia $I$. But what is the nearest possible answer to the question for a free, spinning electron?

In general, one has a relation with spin $J$ given by
$$ J = I \omega.$$
For an electron, the magnitude of spin is $J=\sqrt{3/4} \hbar$. But since $\omega$ is not defined, there is no way to speak about a moment of inertia.

Or can one say more?

Comment: The classical picture of angular momentum doesn’t work for spin angular momentum. Electrons are not actually spinning like a ball.

Comment: True! Indeed, I did not say that they were spinning like a ball - just that they are spinning. There are may other ways to spin...

Comment: I’m not clear on whether you got my point or not. They’re not spinning like *anything* spins in classical mechanics. “Spin” in QM is essentially just a confusing and unfortunate historical *misnomer*.

Comment: See https://motls.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-electron-is-spinning-after-all.html for a different point of view.

Comment: Lubos is a member of PSE, so perhaps he will answer and tell you what the electron’s moment of inertia is.